# No Attribute Retweet_status in tweepy

Tags: python, tweepy

Im trying to retrieve the `retweeted_status` but I am getting the error

`AttributeError: 'Status' object has no attribute 'retweet_status'`

Here is my code. It has worked for me before so not sure if it is broken now, or if syntax for it has changed.

```
with open('C:/Users/User/Desktop/localGovCamp3.csv', 'wb') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)                  
    for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q="@localgovcamp", 
count=1000,result_type="recent",include_entities=True,lang="en").items():

       rt = tweet.retweet_status.id
       print rt
```

Comment: Hey Liam, welcome to stackOverflow. Please give us the complete code so that we understand what's happening. With just one line of code, we really don't know what tweet  variable is

Comment: You should review the Tweepy docs, and make sure the version you think you are using is actually being used, and look at the docs for Cursor to make sure you know what that object contains.

Comment: I have checked all the documentation. All other attributes such as retweeted or reweet_count are working from the Tweet Object. but not retweet_status. I need this to tell me who posted the original tweet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have concluded that retweet_status doesn't work when using Cursor as it works fine with OAuth or Stream.